# I want prove work energy theorem in one dimension .$F(x(t))=m \ddot{x}(t)$

Tags: calculus

I want prove work energy theorem in one dimension . we know that 
$$F(x(t))=m \ddot{x}(t)$$
That proven :

$$\int_{t_a}^{t_b}F(x(t))\cdot dx(t)=\dfrac{1}{2}m\dot x^2(t_b)-\dfrac{1}{2}m\dot x^2(t_a)\tag{1}$$

Now How to prove $(1)$?

Answer (score 2):

I think it should read:

$\int_{t_a}^{t_b}F(x(t))\cdot dx(t)=\dfrac{1}{2}m\dot x(t_b)^2-\dfrac{1}{2}m\dot x(t_a)^2$.

$\int_{t_a}^{t_b}F(x(t))\cdot dx(t)$ is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral and $=\int_{t_a}^{t_b}F(x(t))\cdot \dot x(t) dt.$

Hence

$ \int_{t_a}^{t_b}F(x(t))\cdot dx(t)=m \int_{t_a}^{t_b} \ddot{x}(t) \dot x(t) dt=[m \frac{1}{2} \dot x(t)^2]_{t_a}^{t_b}$.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating the kinetic energy $E(t) = \frac{m}{2}\dot x^2$ you get

- $\dot E = m \dot x \ddot x = F(x) \cdot \dot x$

Now the substitution rule for integration gives immediately
$$\int_{x_a}^{x_b}F(x)dx = \int_{t_a}^{t_b}F(x(t))\dot x dt = \left. \frac{m}{2}\dot x^2(t)\right|_{t_a}^{t_b} = \frac{m}{2}\left(\dot x^2(t_b) -  \dot x^2(t_a)\right) = E(t_b) - E(t_a)$$